# Resending the HTTP request to download a file sent by a button within the browser does not download the file again

Tags: rest, http, web-scraping, browser

**Set up**

I want to download a csv-file via an http request.

Within the browser, i can press a button which then downloads the file.
To check which request i would have to send manually, I looked up which network request is sent after i press the button.

**Error**

It turns out to be a post-request, however when i simply resend the request nothing happens, but i **also** do not receive an error.

When I press the download button twice the download works both times, and both requests only differ in a slightly different timestamp **and** a specific cookie named: ADRUM_BTa

Why does the http-request not work to download the file?

Comment: Where is your source code and example url?

Comment: As im only operating within the browsers network utilities i do not have any code of my own currently. The button itself just calls a function which sends the request (i am not able to view the code of said function tho)

The url is not accessible without login, but looks somewhat like this:
https://www.ec.xyz.com/xyznet/receiveHttps (POST)